# Change VBox to HBox dynamically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

I am in need of a strange solution. I have one requirement in which I am displaying two components in a VBox. But on click of the main container I need to maximize that and need to display the components in horizontal. I was just wondering whether I can change the VBox to HBox and viceversa dynamically using actionscript or some other way.

Thanks in Advance,
Cheers, PK

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [`mx:Box`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/containers/Box.html) and set the `direction` property dynamically.

MXML:

```
<mx:Box id="box" direction="vertical"/>
```

AS3:

```
box.direction = BoxDirection.HORIZONTAL;
```

Comment: Great answer dude... Am very sorry, I want to vote up more than one time :) Thanks very much